# Locker Service creating problem in Jquery Datatable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

jQuery datatable is throwing error when i activate locker service
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Please open a support case on this with specific repro details, specific c library versions, etc and let me know the case ID here. Would you also provide the same repro details here so we can get a jump on investigating it?

Comment: Datatable Library :1.10.10
jQuery JavaScript Library v2.2.4

Comment: if u put simple code in lightining component var a = new Option(2,3); its throwing same error one locker service is  active

Comment: Ah - I see - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option - a bit antiquated and non standard but a de facto standard. Option ctor is not currently supported but we can add it for legacy reasons.

Comment: Hi Daugh thanks for your response,can u provide any official document from salesforce which clearly tell us currently Option Object is not supporting but in future its going to support which help us to take decision regarding my application which is going to be release.

Comment: We will be supporting it. You should be able to use the already supported modern alternative of document.createElement("option")

Comment: What about external library which are using such function which is not supported by locker service

Comment: For that you will need the fix in LS that is being worked on this week. Currently planned to be released a week from Tuesday (next available Summer'16 patch).

Comment: We will evaluate doing the work to get this out earlier once the fix has been implemented.

Comment: when the patch going to be release for  Summer'16 to solve external resource issue

Comment: This did not make it into a sprint yet - still waiting for a developer to become available to work on it (I am swamped). I do not have an ETA yet.

Comment: @DougChasman The issue seems to be resolved now with the latest patch.
The only change we had to do is replacing the old Jquery(1.11) with a recent one (Jquery 2.1).
It is still not working with Jquery(1.11)

Comment: @DougChasman I'm getting the option error "Failed to construct 'Option': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function." using jQuery 2.2.4 or jQuery 3.1.1 with DataTables 1.10.12. Here's gist with code to reproduce error: https://gist.github.com/DouglasCAyers/bbb2dda43a959562b03438352722773d Also, thanks for the follow up on my other gist a few days ago =) Unfortunately, github doesn't send me notifications for gist comments.

Comment: @DougChasman A workaround to at least get the table to render is to set the `dom` setting of DataTables to empty string: `dom: ''` https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom

Comment: @DougChasman did some more testing, the only `dom` option from DataTables that gives the error is `l`, the page size length setting, which builds a select input. The other dom options don't build select inputs and work fine.

Answer (score 0):

@Doug Chasman : We are facing the same issue. Thank you very much for your quick help. But the same thing works with LockerService prerelease orgs. We see the problem only when we activate LockerService in existing orgs (tested in Sandbox only) as the main release is scheduled this weekend.

Also, I appreciate if you can help us with any alternate solution for the time being. Any ETA to add the Option ctor.

Comment: This issue will happen in any org where the components are running in LS and there are multiple scenarios for this - the org's where it is working are grandfathered or running managed components etc.